# How to trigger a type family pattern match error in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

Is Haskell able to indicate a type family match error? For example, using a closed type family:

```
type family Testf a where
  Testf Char   = IO ()
  Testf String = IO ()
```

The type of `Testf Int` is just `Testf Int`. The compiler does not generate any kind of error. Is it possible to get it to generate one if there are no matches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not possible. Well-kinded type family applications never trigger errors by themselves. Instead, we only get type errors when we try to use unreduced type family expressions for something.

We can use custom types holding error messages, in order to make errors a bit clearer:

```
import GHC.TypeLits

data Error (msg :: Symbol) -- a type-level error message

type family Testf a where
  Testf Char   = IO ()
  Testf String = IO ()
  Testf x      = Error "No match for Testf"
```

Now, GHC throws an error and consequently prints our message whenever we try to use `Error msg` to type a non-undefined value.

From GHC 8.0, we can use [`TypeError`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#custom-compile-time-errors) to print our message in a nicer way:

```
{-# language DataKinds #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

type family Testf a where
  Testf Char   = IO ()
  Testf String = IO ()
  Testf x      = TypeError (Text "No matching case for Testf")
```

This would print:

```
Notes.hs:18:5: error: …
    • No matching case for Testf
    • In the expression: ...
```

However, this still only throws the error on use:

```
type T = Testf Int -- this typechecks

x :: T
x = () -- we throw error only here
```

Comment: GHC 8.0 offers something like this in `TypeLits`, with special type checker support to make the errors look good.

Comment: Good find, added reference to that.

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible in GHCs before 8.0, but [the (as of this writing) just-released GHC 8.0.1](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/blog/ghc-8.0.1-released) adds support for [custom type errors](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#custom-errors).

The idea is that, just like the function `error :: String -> a` inhabits any type with an error at the term level, we now have, [in `GHC.TypeLits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#g:4), the type family

```
type family TypeError (msg :: ErrorMessage) :: k
```

that inhabits any *type* with a *type error*.  The `ErrorMessage` type is very simple:

```
data ErrorMessage = Text     Symbol
                  | ShowType t
                  | ErrorMessage :<>: ErrorMessage
                  | ErrorMessage :$$: ErrorMessage
```

The `(:<>:)` constructor concatenates two error messages horizontally; the `(:$$:)` constructor concatenates them vertically.  The other two constructors do what they say.

Thus, in your example, you can fill in the last case with a `TypeError`; for instance,

```
type family Testf a where
  Testf Char   = IO ()
  Testf String = IO ()
  Testf a      = TypeError (    Text "‘Testf’ didn't match"
                           :$$: Text "when applied to the type ‘"
                                :<>: ShowType a :<>: Text "’")
```

Then, trying to use `pure ()` at type `Testf Int` will fail with the error

```
....hs:19:12: error: …
    • ‘Testf’ didn't match
      when applied to the type ‘Int’
    • In the expression: pure ()
      In an equation for ‘testfInt’: testfInt = pure ()
Compilation failed.
```

Note that while defining

```
testfInt :: Testf Int
testfInt = pure ()
```

correctly broke, defining

```
testfInt :: Testf Int
testfInt = undefined
```

(or similarly with `testfInt = testfInt`) worked fine.

---

Here's a full example source file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

type family Testf a where
  Testf Char   = IO ()
  Testf String = IO ()
  Testf a      = TypeError (    Text "‘Testf’ didn't match"
                           :$$: Text "when applied to the type ‘"
                                :<>: ShowType a :<>: Text "’")

testfChar :: Testf Char
testfChar = putStrLn "Testf Char"

testfString :: Testf Char
testfString = putStrLn "Testf String"

-- Error here!
testfInt :: Testf Int
testfInt = putStrLn "Int"
```